# Came across data type issue when populating new column with pandas dataframe functions

Tags: python, pandas

Dears,

I have a requirement that read a csv file, populate 3 new columns base on simple divide calculation of 3 existing columns(the elements are number with two decimal places), then generate a new csv file.
I have tried 2 approaches with individual snippet to achieve the purpose, but failed with errors.

**Approach 1:**

```
from numpy import *
import pandas as pd

def func_process(file_in, file_out):
    df = pd.read_csv(file_in)
    df.eval("""col1_new = col1 / 2
    col2_new = col2 / 4
    col3_new = col3 / 8
    """, inplace=True)
    df.to_csv(file_out, encoding='utf-8', index=False)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    input_file = 'C:/temp/csv/in/test.csv'
    output_file = 'C:temp/csv/out/result.csv'
    func_process(input_file, output_file)
```

=======================================================

After i ran the function, i got error
***TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'object' and '<class 'int'>'***

**Approach 2**

```
from numpy import *
import pandas as pd

def my_test(a, b):
    return a / b

def func_process(file_in, file_out):
    df = pd.read_csv(file_in)
    df['col1_new'] = df.apply(lambda x: my_test(x['col1'], 2), axis=1)
    df['col2_new'] = df.apply(lambda x: my_test(x['col2'], 4), axis=1)
    df['col3_new'] = df.apply(lambda x: my_test(x['col3'], 8), axis=1)
    df.to_csv(file_out, encoding='utf-8', index=False)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    input_file = 'C:/temp/csv/in/test.csv'
    output_file = 'C:temp/csv/out/result.csv'
    func_process(input_file, output_file)
```

=======================================================

After i ran the function, i got error
***TypeError: "unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'str' and 'int'", 'occurred at index 0')***

I think I'm struggling with these type errors, could you guys help me here?

Thanks,
cea

Comment: Always provide a [mre] **with code, data, errors, current output, and expected output, as text**. If relevant, plot images are okay. Please see [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Please accept my answer as solution by clicking the checkmark next to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You have strings in your columns. You can change to numeric data, and make strings go to `NaN` with `pd.to_numeric` and pass `errors='coerce'`. You can also cast to `.astype(float)` or `.astype(int)`:

```
def func_process(file_in, file_out):
    df = pd.read_csv(file_in)
    df['col1_new'] = pd.to_numeric(df['col1_new'], errors='coerce').astype(float)
    df['col2_new'] = pd.to_numeric(df['col2_new'], errors='coerce').astype(float)
    df['col3_new'] = pd.to_numeric(df['col3_new'], errors='coerce').astype(float)
    df['col1_new'] = df.apply(lambda x: my_test(x['col1'], 2), axis=1)
    df['col2_new'] = df.apply(lambda x: my_test(x['col2'], 4), axis=1)
    df['col3_new'] = df.apply(lambda x: my_test(x['col3'], 8), axis=1)
    df.to_csv(file_out, encoding='utf-8', index=False)
```

Comment: Awesome, Erickson. It released me. Gr8 thnx !

Comment: @ceasarsw Excellent! Please accept as solution by clicking the checkmark button next my solution.

Comment: Hi David, based on the neat snippet you provided, i have another question, if my col1 elements value are numeric data greater than 10000000000 such as 19,660,357,580.82     what data type can i fill within the astype() of pd.to_numeric(df['col1'], errors='coerce').astype(???)

Comment: Use astype(float)